# Spark mapping on nested WrappedArrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to compute word co-occurrence using spark 2.1

My input data looks like:

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|           keywords|
+---+-------------------+
|  8|       [mouse, cat]|
|  9|         [bat, cat]|
| 10|[mouse, house, cat]|
+---+-------------------+
```

My desired result is the combinations of keywords across those rows as in:

```
+-------+--------+
| word1 |  word2 |
+-------+--------+
| cat   |  mouse |
| bat   |  cat   |
| cat   |  house |
| cat   |  mouse |
| house |  mouse |
+-------+--------+
```

Since the input rows rarely have more than 20 or so keywords Scala's combinations() seems adequate to build up the occurrence pairs.

Given a fn and UDF that wraps it as:

```
def combine(items: Seq[String]) = {
  items.sorted.combinations(2).toList
}
val combineUDF = udf(combine _)
```

Using a simple sequence I can get the pairs of occurring keywords as in:

```
val simpleSeq = Seq("cat", "mouse", "house")
println(combine(simpleSeq)

List(List(cat, house), List(cat, mouse), List(house, mouse))
```

**Using Dataframes**
Using a dataframe of my input data as in:

```
val comboDF = sourceDF.withColumn("combinations", combineUDF($"keywords"))

comboDF.printSchema
comboDF.show

comboDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, keywords: array<string> ... 1 more field]
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- keywords: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- combinations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
| id|           keywords|        combinations|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
|  9|       [mouse, cat]|[WrappedArray(cat...|
|  8|         [bat, cat]|[WrappedArray(bat...|
| 10|[mouse, house, cat]|[WrappedArray(cat...|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I next want to **extract each of the pairs in the combinations column with each pair as a row**.

I cant figure out how to do that.

The added column is of type `[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]]` which I dont seem to be able to map over:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

comboDF.map(row => row.get(2).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Seq[String]]].array).show

<console>:55: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       comboDF.map(row => row.get(2).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Seq[String]]].array).show
```

**Using RDD**

To get around the apparent inability for DF based to handle nested wrapped arrays, I tried RDDs (which I am not as familiar with).

I can get the combinations of keywords per row via:

```
val wrappedPairs = listDF.select("keywords").
   rdd.collect.map(r => 
     combine(r.get(0).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]].array.toList)

Array[List[Seq[String]]] = Array(List(List(cat, mouse)), List(List(bat, cat)), List(List(cat, house), List(cat, mouse), List(house, mouse)))
```

This basically gives me:

```
Array(
  List(
    List(cat, mouse)
  ), 
  List(
    List(bat, cat)
  ), 
  List(
    List(cat, house), 
    List(cat, mouse), 
    List(house, mouse)
  )
)
```

and I want to get to:

```
+-------+--------+
| word1 |  word2 |
+-------+--------+
| cat   |  mouse |
| bat   |  cat   |
| cat   |  house |
| cat   |  mouse |
| house |  mouse |
+-------+--------+
```

I can get the pairs using println but cant seem to work out how to lift them out as rows:

```
wrappedPairs.map(outerList => outerList.asInstanceOf[List[List[String]]].
    map(innerList => innerList.asInstanceOf[List[String]]).
        map(pair => (pair(0),pair(1).toSeq)).foreach(println)
    )


wrappedPairs: Array[List[Seq[String]]] = Array(List(List(cat, mouse)), List(List(bat, cat)), List(List(cat, house), List(cat, mouse), List(house, mouse)))
(cat,mouse)
(bat,cat)
(cat,house)
(cat,mouse)
(house,mouse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close!  The two things you need are `explode` and how to project fields from a struct type out.  `explode` will expand a list of items in a row out to individual rows (duplicating all the other fields).  After the explode you need to select out values inside the arrays in "combinations".  There are a couple ways to do this, but I usually do it the way shown below.

Check out this sample code:

```
val input = Seq(
    (Seq("mouse", "cat")),
    (Seq("bat", "cat")),
    (Seq("mouse", "house", "cat"))
).toDF("keywords")

def combine(items: Seq[String]) = {
  items.sorted.combinations(2).toList
}
val combineUDF = udf(combine _)

val df = input.withColumn("combinations", explode(combineUDF($"keywords")))
df.show
```

That would get you a DataFrame like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+
|           keywords|  combinations|
+-------------------+--------------+
|       [mouse, cat]|  [cat, mouse]|
|         [bat, cat]|    [bat, cat]|
|[mouse, house, cat]|  [cat, house]|
|[mouse, house, cat]|  [cat, mouse]|
|[mouse, house, cat]|[house, mouse]|
+-------------------+--------------+
```

Now you can just select the two fields out of the array in each Row like this:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr("combinations[0] as word1", "combinations[1] as word2")
df2.show
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
|word1|word2|
+-----+-----+
|  cat|mouse|
|  bat|  cat|
|  cat|house|
|  cat|mouse|
|house|mouse|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks much. I knew it could be simpler/more elegant than the rabbit hole I had wandered down.